# document.getElementById.checked=true not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm writing a code to select a value from a drop-down list and the radio button will automatically checked itself according to the onClick attribute. The code worked both in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome.

This is the code for the drop-down list:

```
<select name="c_DOB_year" id="c_DOB_year">
    <option selected="selected">Year</option>
    <option value="2008" onClick="document.getElementById('c_age_2').checked=true;">2008</option>
    <option value="2009" onClick="document.getElementById('c_age_1').checked=true;">2009</option>
    <option value="2010" onClick="document.getElementById('c_age_0').checked=true;">2010</option>
</select>
```

This is the code for the radio button:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_age" value="4 Years" id="c_age_0" />
    4 Years
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_age" value="5 Years" id="c_age_1" />
    5 Years
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_age" value="6 Years" id="c_age_2" />
    6 Years
</label>
```

What seems to be the problem? Hope someone can help me. Thanks. :D

Comment: Check your JavaScript console (F12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the click event is valid on options. It is valid, however, on select elements. Give this a try:

```
var d= {
    '2008':'c_age_2',
    '2009':'c_age_1',
    '2010':'c_age_0',
};
var ele = document.getElementById('c_DOB_year');
ele.onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById(d[ele.value]).checked=true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

HTML

```
    <select onChange="jsFunction()" id="selectOpt">
    <option selected="selected">Year</option>
    <option id="c_age_2">2008</option>
    <option id="c_age_1">2009</option>
    <option id="c_age_0">2010</option>
    </select>
```

Script

```
  function jsFunction(){
  var myselect = document.getElementById("selectOpt");
  var val=myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].id;
    document.getElementById(val).checked=true;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n5CcV/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Move the eventhandler to the `select` elements `onchange` event and attach the event in script.  This will allow you to clean up the markup some, but will require you to do the math to figure out the year.

**HTML**

```
<select name="c_DOB_year" id="c_DOB_year">
<option selected="selected">Year</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
</select>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_age" value="4 Years"/>
    4 Years
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_age" value="5 Years"/>
    5 Years
</label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="c_age" value="6 Years"/>
    6 Years
</label>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("c_DOB_year").onchange = function(){
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
            radios[i].checked = radios[i].value.split(" ")[0] == new Date().getFullYear() - this.value+1;
    }
};
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mncm8/1/

This may depend on the business logic but I noticed the years and corresponding dates were out of line.  2008 is 5 Years before 2013, 2009 is 4 years before 2013 and 2010 is 3 years before 2013.  If this is correct logic, simply remove the `+1` from the line, `radios[i].checked = radios[i].value.split(" ")[0] == new Date().getFullYear() - this.value+1;` to implement.

Comment: Thanks for noticing about the years and corresponding dates. Can you explain a bit more about the calculation?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add events to a `SELECT's` options. Add an `onchange` event to the `SELECT` control instead